# Testear performance de pagina web/Server

Tags: aplicación-web, servidor, web

Tengo una pagina web realizada con laravel y mysql,y tiene bastante acceso a base de datos, y quisiera saber como medir cuantos usuarios simultáneos realizando consultas aguanta mi pagina.

Tengo un servidor básico en digital ocean con las siguientes características:

> 512 MB (1 CPU)
>   20 GB (SSD DISK)
>   1000 GB (Transfer)

y tiene muchos servidores distintos y el mas alto tiene las caracteristicas:

> 224 GB (1 CPU)
>   500 GB (SSD DISK)
>   10 TB (Transfer)

Realmente mucha diferencia, pero mas alla de eso, no se cuando utilizar uno y cuando ir escalando a otro, que seria escalar verticalmente. A su vez no se cuando escalar horizontalmente, es decir realizar replicas del sistema, o tener un servidor que sea solo para la base de datos.

Realmente me gustaría saber estas cuestiones, antes de tener problemas futuros, por mas que sean pocos usuarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrígeme si me equivoco, cuando un usuario solicita una página a tu sistema, se abre una conexión a la base de datos, se realizan las consultas que se requieran, se muestra la página y se cierra la conexión. Esta operación tarda digamos, que 2 segundos. El usuario puede estar *leyendo* tu página, digamos 10 minutos.

Si tu base de datos acepta 3 conexiones simultáneas, puedes servir 3 conexiones cada 2 segundos o 90 conexiones por minuto.

Pero aunque 90 usuarios estén leyendo tu página **al mismo tiempo** no son conexiones simultáneas, porque la página en cuestión **ya está en el cliente**.

Si al mismo tiempo llegaran 5 clientes a solicitar la página, y tu servidor de base de datos acepta 3 conexiones simultáneas, dos de esos clientes esperarían 2 segundos en ver tu página. Si aumentas el límite de MySQL a 5, entonces podrías servir 150 páginas cada minuto.

Evidentemente, entre más conexiones abiertas permitas, más recursos consume tu sistema.

La solución este es usar memorias temporales, ***cache***, a las consultas de tu base de datos y a las páginas generadas por PHP. Este cache, digamos que reduce el tiempo de respuesta a 1/2 segundo.

Ahora pasamos a tu servidor http. Si tu servidor acepta 50 clientes simultáneamente, sirviendo en 1/2 las páginas cacheadas, puede servir 100 páginas simultáneas **por segundo**.

Pero es lo mismo, abre una conexión, sirve la página y cierra... **no hay usuarios simultáneos**.

> Esto cambia si haces uso de websockets, pero no lo indicas en tu pregunta.

## Respuesta

Apache tiene un programa llamado [**ab**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) que sirve para hacer pruebas de esfuerzo o *benchmarking*. Muestra el número de **solicitudes** por segundo puede servir tu servidor Apache, _aunque creo que funciona para cualquier servidor, porque hace las pruebas bajo el protocolo `http`.

Se usa así:

```
ab -n 200 -c 20 http://example.com
```

Con esto generas 100 solicitudes en 20 hilos, para verificar la concurrencia. En esta página de [genbeta:dev](http://www.genbetadev.com/herramientas/apachebench-una-sencilla-herramienta-para-testear-servidores-web) puedes ver un ejemplo.

> #### Recomendaciones
>
> A menos que sepas con certeza que tu sistema tiene requisitos de memoria muy altos, deberías considerar optimizar tu código, utilizar cache y optimizar tus servidores **antes** de pensar en escalar tus servidores. Un sistema mal programado y/o mal optimizado tendrá un desempeño pobre en un servidor con 1 GB o con 224 Gb.

Comment: Sobre lo que dijiste, tengo que ver eso del límite de  las conexiones simultáneas que permite la Bd y el servidor, ya que es el numero que me esta faltando. voy a probar el benchmarking y la optimization que son cosas que aún desconozco.

Comment: Como te vuelvo a repetir, primero busca mejorar tu propio código, antes de optimizar cosas que seguramente ya están optimizadas o pagar por algo que no necesitas.

Comment: Cuando decís optimizar el código, es optimizar el código php, sql, htaccess no?

Comment: Si. Muchas veces nos negamos a pensar que nuestro código puede mejorarse (porque nosotros lo escribimos) y buscamos la causa de un rendimiento pobre en los recursos como memoria, disco, etc. También es común pensar en optimizar son conocer el rendimiento actual